# How to render JSF tags on html page from String field in a bean

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

How can I render JSF tags like HTML tags?

For example I have some html code in a string field:

```
<pre>String code = "example <br/> example";</pre>
```

If I use

```
<pre><h:outputText value="#{bean.code}" escape="false"/></pre>
```

I will get

```
<pre>example
example</pre>
```

Now I want to render jsf component in the same way. For example:

```
 <pre>String code = '<h:button value="something" action="something"/>';</pre>
```

But it will be rendered as it is. As I think it must be translated first by JSF servlet to html tags. How could I render JSF controlls in that way? I've got texts containing lots of JSF controls (articles) stored in a database and I need to easy render JSF controlls from that.

Comment: A very bad idea. Why do you need this? Why don't you use Facelet templates or composite components?

Comment: I'm storing articles (somethin like blog) in a database column for example articleText. I can't store that in a file because I can't add new files to running application (I'm using Google App Engine). All tags are stored in database field. And I'm adding this to html page as <h:outputText value="#{bean.articleText}" escape="false"/>.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea. The JSF tags has to go in a Facelet file and the text has to go in DB. You should not manually add JSF tags to the text before storing in DB. You should do it in the Facelet file while displaying text from DB. That's how the "V" of MVC is supposed to work.

If you *really* insist to do so (this is prone to security attacks and you have to do a lot of validation to prevent that), then best what you could do is to create a Facelets `ResourceResolver` which gets the data from the DB, saves it as a Facelet file in memory or on disk and returns the `URL` to it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't create new files on the fly due to Google App Engine limitations. So I wanted to store some page markup in the database. If not I will must add new file and redeploy app to GAE. I will search for some other ways to doing this. Thank you for answers.

Comment: I am not recommending that. It's only good that GAE doesn't allow that. You definitely need to rethink/redesign your approach.